# 2 approaches for tracking online users with Redis. Which one is faster?

Tags: performance, comparison, redis

Recently I found an nice blog post presenting 2 approaches for tracking online users of a web site with the help of Redis.

1) Smart-keys and setting their expiration
http://techno-weenie.net/2010/2/3/where-s-waldo-track-user-locations-with-node-js-and-redis

2) Set-s and intersects
http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2010/01/17/redis-in-practice-whos-online/

Can you judge which one should be faster and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For knowing whether or not a particular user is online, the first method will be a lot faster - nothing is faster than reading a single key.

Finding users on a particular page is not as clear (I haven't seen hard numbers on the performance of either intersection or wildcard keys), but if the set is big enough to cause performance problems in either implementation it isn't practical to display them all anyway.

For matching users to a friends list I would probably go with the first approach also - even a few hundred get operations (checking the status of everyone in the list) should outperform intersection on multiple sets if those sets have a large number of records and are difficult to maintain.

Redis sets are more appropriate for things that can't be done with keys, particularly where getting all items in the set is more important than checking if a particular item is in the set.

Comment: Unless your redis library is pipelined, a few hundred GET operations could be very slow simply due to network latency.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/101970/tom-clarkson
SADD and SISMEMBER are both O(1) which is the same complexity as SET and GET so, respectfully, why do you say "nothing is faster than reading a single key"?  :-)  Do you have stats to show that SET/GET performs much better than SADD/SISMEMBER?

I mean this out of genuine intellectual curiosity and without any intent to start a flame war ...

Comment: @Joel complexity is but one aspect of performance and while two operations may exhibit the same complexity it does not necessarily mean that the two have the same performance. As for the topic at hand, on my laptop, redis-benchmark does 48K/sec SET operations vs 52K/sec SADDs :)

Comment: @ItamarHaber fair enough.  But big O notation is all about worst case performance for large problem size n.  You're right, average case complexity could be different.  Don't your benchmarks show that SADD is faster than plain SET?  :-)

Comment: @Joel Exactly, O(1) != O(1) :)