# Tracking online users using Redis

Tags: redis

I want to track how many users are online, I use Redis to solve this problem as one or more number of application instances access this cache to display the statuses. On every new login the Redis is updated with the user-id, on the key "online_users", and on every logout the user is removed. Is this approach right, if not how to structure this for best performance, and somewhat big dataset?

```
"online_users" -> {
     user_s23,user_1f3,user_1mn,user_xd3
}
```

The user info is available in the cache as, is it right to include the status as another attribute?

```
user_s23 {
name, id, profile_pic, type, etc, status:active/inactive
}
```

Though this [2 approaches for tracking online users with Redis. Which one is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644021/2-approaches-for-tracking-online-users-with-redis-which-one-is-faster) question's answer compares two approaches on this, the first link mentioned is unavailable, so I could not understand the other context.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you only want to know:

1- How many users are online

2- What users are online

3- Find if a given user is online

And you can ensure that you can track **EVERY** logout and **ALL** users call the logout request, then you can use a `set` and store the user id into it when user logs in and removes the userid when the user logs out (the same approach as you described).

Examples:

- user_a logs in:

> > sadd online_users user_a
>
> (integer) 1

- user_b logs in:

> > sadd online_users user_b
>
> (integer) 1

- How many users are online?

> > scard online_users
>
> (integer) 2

- Is user_a online?

> > sismember online_users user_a
>
> (integer) 1

- user_a logs out:

> > srem online_users user_a
>
> (integer) 1

- What users are online?

> > smembers online_users
>
> 1) "user_b"

All these operations are O(1) except the `smembers` that is O(N), your only concern and limit is the memory used to store these data. A hint is to try to use smaller keys for your users, if you can't, Redis already compress them.

If you can't ensure that you will track the logouts, you can use the second approach of the question "2 approaches for tracking online users with Redis. Which one is faster?".

To use this approach you will need to track all events of a user (not only the login), and store the user id on different keys using a time stamp, like: online_users_2014-02-20_10-01 (online users at 10:01 of 02/20/2014).

To answer how many users are currently online, you can say, for example, that a user is considered online if he sent at least one event in the last 3 minutes. Then you calculate the union of the last 3 sets and use scard on the resulting set to find how many users are online.

This approach is much more expensive, because `sunion` is O(N). And is a good idea to add timeout (using the `expire` command) on your keys to keep help clean your memory.

Another approach based on the last one, is to add some logic on the client side, that send a PING event every minute in background for your backend, then you can track this event and you will have sure that the users in that set are online.

Comment: This approach is a good one, I will implement this approach and test the performance in a high volume.

Answer (score 5):

1)

In terms of performance and memory used I think the best approach is to use a [bitset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) structure, in this way, each user is represented as a single bit and Redis has lots of commands (setbit, bitcount, bitop, getbit) to work with this structure.

The only requirement to use this approach is that you need a unique sequential id for each user.

Example:

1 - User 43 logs in

> > setbit online_users 43 1
>
> (integer) 0

2 - User 57 logs in

> > setbit online_users 57 1
>
> (integer) 0

3 - Total users online

> > bitcount online_users
>
> (integer) 2

4 - User 43 logs out

> > setbit online_users 43 0
>
> (integer) 1

5 - Total users online

> > bitcount online_users
>
> (integer) 1

6 - Check if user 57 is online

> > getbit online_users 57
>
> (integer) 1

2) It is ok to set a new attribute into your user structure to track a user status, but maybe it is easier to check directly into the online_users bitset for this value (use the getbit command).

3) A cached version of the first link can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110117191451/http://techno-weenie.net/2010/2/3/where-s-waldo-track-user-locations-with-node-js-and-redis)

In terms of memory and performance, using a bitset is better than the approches of the other question.

By the way, I would not use a approach using the `KEYS` command because it can be a bottleneck when the dataset is big.

You can find my information about this approach on the  documentation page of BITCOUNT Redis command.

Comment: The approach you have prescribed is good, but I have only text id for the user and not a numerical one. so, setbit online_users xxxx123 1 throws error. More to this, how do I find the list of users online?

Comment: You really need to have unique sequential id for each user to use this approach.

Comment: You really need to have unique sequential id for each user to use this approach, and is expensive to determine to list of online users, but it is simple to check if a given user is online.

In your question, you said that you want to track how many users are  online, but I will post another solution to allow you to track the user that are online.